# Retrieving Form Data with PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to put together a form that will allow me to create a shopping cart application for a PHP class. For the purposes of this, we are supposed to display our form information repeatedly. While I'm familiar with storing information, I do not know how to retrieve that stored information, and we haven't really gone into any detail on storing or retrieving data from the database, yet.

Currently, I have the first form, which has a list of radio buttons and items, like so:

```
            <form action="shoppingCart.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="1" />

                <table id="shoppingList">                   
                    <tr class="d0">
                        <td class="rad"><input type="radio" name="items" value="oolongTea"></td>
                        <td class="item">Oolong Tea</td>
                    </tr>
            ...
```

This list continues on like this for 10 items. When I click the next button, it submits that data to the form, and then proceeds onto the next page. Where does that data go, I suppose is my question, and how would I go about getting it back?

I should add that I also have this block at the top of my code, for checking which form to display:

```
        if ( isset( $_POST["step"] ) and $_POST["step"] >= 1 and $_POST["step"] <= 3 ) {
          call_user_func( "processStep" . (int)$_POST["step"] );
        } else {
          displayStep1();
        }
```

And this block is the block that handles the "processing" of the first form:

```
        function processStep1() {
            $_SESSION["items"] = $_POST["items"];
            displayStep2();
        }
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? Do you want to just retrieve the posted values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data submitted for

```
<input type="radio" name="items" value="oolongTea">
```

can be found in

```
$_POST["items"];
```

so if you selected that radio button and submitted the form, $_POST["items"] would be equal to the value attribute on that input tag ("oolongTea")

Comment: That was.. surprisingly easy. Alrighty then. Thank you!

Comment: Any time. Happy to be able to help :)